# Image and plotly plot side by side in R markdown

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am trying to show an image and a plot (plotly gauge) side-by-side in R markdown, however only a blank graph shows for the image. I have imported the image into plotly and am attempting to use subplot to show them side by side. Any advice on what I'm missing?

```
# Photo
photo <- plot_ly(domain = list(x = c(0, 0.5), y = c(0, 1)))%>%
  layout(
    images = list(source =  "C:/Users/Name/Documents//Image.PNG"
      ))

# Gauge value
x <- mean(df$variable)

# Plot
fig1 <- plot_ly(
  value = x,
  number = list(suffix = "%"),
  title = list(text = "Title"),
  type = "indicator",
  mode = "gauge+number",
  gauge = list(
    axis =list(range = list(NULL, 100)),
    steps = list(
      list(range = c(0, 78), color = "white"),
      list(range = c(78, 88), color = "green"),
      list(range = c(88, 100), color = "white")),
    bar = list(color = "black")),
  domain = list(x = c(0.5, 1), y = c(0, 1)))

subplot(photo, add_trace(fig1))
```

Comment: What output is your YAML set to? `html_document`, `pdf_document`, `flextable`? I think I can offer a solution, but the solution relies of the output type.

Comment: Currently html, but I can do pdf as well depending on what the solution relies on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try in RMarkdown but I would try this:

```
library(plotly)
library(EBImage) # BiocManager::install("EBImage")

p1 <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~pop)

img <- readImage("mobiussolid.png")
p2 <- plot_ly(type = "image", z = img*255) %>% 
  layout(margin=list(l=10, r=10, b=0, t=0),
         xaxis=list(showticklabels=FALSE, ticks=""),
         yaxis=list(showticklabels=FALSE, ticks=""))

subplot(p1, p2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The EBImage library did not agree with RMarkdown, however, I imported the image using OpenImageR followed by your suggestion for plotly script, and this worked. It does increase the runtime substantially, so I will continue to try other solutions if I come across them and will update the post if I find something. I appreciate the help!